# TSQL Group by Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a simple query that is parsing through some records / XML and doing some math for me. It is then returning an output of XML with the numbers I need.

```
SELECT  A.[reimbursementDate],
                MONTH(A.[reimbursementDate]) as reimbursementMonth,
                YEAR(A.[reimbursementDate]) as reimbursementYear,
            (
                SELECT  SUM(ParamValues.x2.value('grandTotal[1]', 'INT')) as grandTotal,
                        SUM(ParamValues.x2.value('booksTotal[1]', 'INT')) as totalBooks,
                        SUM(ParamValues.x2.value('tuitionTotal[1]', 'INT')) as tuitionTotal
                FROM    A.[classXML].nodes('/courses') AS ParamValues(x2)
                FOR    XML PATH (''), TYPE, ELEMENTS
            )
        FROM   tuitionSubmissions as A
        WHERE A.[status] = 'Approved' AND YEAR(A.[reimbursementDate]) = YEAR(GETDATE())
        GROUP BY A.[reimbursementDate]
        FOR    XML PATH ('dataSet'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

Below you will see the output that this is generating:

```
            <root>
              <dataSet>
                <reimbursementMonth>6</reimbursementMonth>
                <reimbursementYear>2014</reimbursementYear>
                <grandTuition>1158</grandTuition>
                <totalBooks>863</totalBooks>
                <tuitionTotal>295</tuitionTotal>
              </dataSet>
              <dataSet>
                <reimbursementMonth>8</reimbursementMonth>
                <reimbursementYear>2014</reimbursementYear>
                <grandTuition>253</grandTuition>
                <totalBooks>143</totalBooks>
                <tuitionTotal>110</tuitionTotal>
              </dataSet>
              <dataSet>
                <reimbursementMonth>7</reimbursementMonth>
                <reimbursementYear>2014</reimbursementYear>
                <grandTuition>1488</grandTuition>
                <totalBooks>842</totalBooks>
                <tuitionTotal>986</tuitionTotal>
              </dataSet>
              <dataSet>
                <reimbursementMonth>6</reimbursementMonth>
                <reimbursementYear>2014</reimbursementYear>
                <grandTuition>616</grandTuition>
                <totalBooks>425</totalBooks>
                <tuitionTotal>191</tuitionTotal>
              </dataSet>
            </root>
```

My issue is that I want to combine the numbers where the month / year is the same. So the first block and the last block are month 6 so those should be combined into one with their totals. Is there an easy way I can do this from my query ?

Comment: I had tried groupBY but I got this error: `Column 'tuitionSubmissions.reimbursementDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: The error message is more than clear. You must have the all columns you are selected either in the `group by` or the `aggregate`.

Comment: There is only 1 column though in my select that I'm grouping by `A.[reimbursementDate]`. I am just getting the year and month from that.

Comment: You must show the problematic query instead of successful.

Comment: `A.[reimbursementDate]` is a column, `MONTH(A.[reimbursementDate])` is another column, etc. Each item in a `SELECT` needs to be contained in the `GROUP BY` or an aggregate if any items are in an aggregate/group by.

Comment: Updated the post with the one line I was missing to show the error explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must you this, if you want to group also by month and year

```
SELECT  A.[reimbursementDate],
            MONTH(A.[reimbursementDate]) as reimbursementMonth,
            YEAR(A.[reimbursementDate]) as reimbursementYear,
        (
            SELECT  SUM(ParamValues.x2.value('grandTotal[1]', 'INT')) as grandTotal,
                    SUM(ParamValues.x2.value('booksTotal[1]', 'INT')) as totalBooks,
                    SUM(ParamValues.x2.value('tuitionTotal[1]', 'INT')) as tuitionTotal
            FROM    A.[classXML].nodes('/courses') AS ParamValues(x2)
            FOR    XML PATH (''), TYPE, ELEMENTS
        )
    FROM   tuitionSubmissions as A
    WHERE A.[status] = 'Approved' AND YEAR(A.[reimbursementDate]) = YEAR(GETDATE())
    GROUP BY A.[reimbursementDate]
            MONTH(A.[reimbursementDate])
            YEAR(A.[reimbursementDate])
    FOR    XML PATH ('dataSet'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

or this, if you want to group only by `reimbursementDate`

```
SELECT
  [reimbursementDate],
   MONTH([reimbursementDate]) as reimbursementMonth,
   YEAR([reimbursementDate]) as reimbursementYear,
   XMLCol
FROM
(
    SELECT  A.[reimbursementDate],
        (
            SELECT  SUM(ParamValues.x2.value('grandTotal[1]', 'INT')) as grandTotal,
                    SUM(ParamValues.x2.value('booksTotal[1]', 'INT')) as totalBooks,
                    SUM(ParamValues.x2.value('tuitionTotal[1]', 'INT')) as tuitionTotal
            FROM    A.[classXML].nodes('/courses') AS ParamValues(x2)
            FOR    XML PATH (''), TYPE, ELEMENTS
        ) as XMLCol
    FROM   tuitionSubmissions as A
    WHERE A.[status] = 'Approved' AND YEAR(A.[reimbursementDate]) = YEAR(GETDATE())
    GROUP BY A.[reimbursementDate]
            MONTH(A.[reimbursementDate])
            YEAR(A.[reimbursementDate])
    FOR    XML PATH ('dataSet'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root')
) T
```

Comment: When using your first example, I get this error. `A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.` Not sure if thats related to the query or not ?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you use. Show result of the `SELECT @@VERSION` command.

Comment: `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) 
 Apr  2 2010 15:48:46 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)`

Comment: Install Service Pack 2

Comment: okay... I will see if that's possible - its an issue with the group by clause as it works without it.

Comment: It is not issue, it problem with your very old SQL Server. Is it a  production server?

Comment: There are 2 , Development and Production. Not sure what is on production but I assume you would tell me to update it if it was the same :)